# How to check error in omegle integration with nodejs (UNHANDLED EXCEPTION)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am using omegle integration in nodejs, and I've got a program which connects to an omegle client, receives his messages and sends it back as a repeater(just to check proper working of connection). While this an unhandled error occurs which forces the server to close.
How can I handled this error below??
I have used try, catch, finally and also the uncaughtException method provided by nodejs..
Help me out...!!

```
ERROR-->
event.js:72
       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error:connecr ETIMEDOUT
      at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:875:19)
```

MY CODE-->

```
     var Omegle, om, start;
        Omegle = require('../lib/omegle').Omegle;
        om = new Omegle();
        om.on('recaptchaRequired', function(key) {
  return console.log("Recaptcha Required: " + key);
});
om.on('gotMessage', function(msg) {
  var repeat;
  console.log("Got message: " + msg);
  repeat = function() {
    var sent;
    sent = "You said: " + msg;
    return om.send(sent, function(err) {
      return console.log(!err ? "Message sent: " + sent : "Error: " + err);
    });
  };
  om.startTyping(function() {
    return console.log("We started typing");
  });
  return setTimeout(repeat, 800);
});
om.on('strangerDisconnected', function() {
  console.log("Stranger disconnected");
  return start();
});
om.on('typing', function() {
  return console.log('Stranger started typing');
});
om.on('stoppedTyping', function() {
  return console.log('Stranger stopped typing');
});
start = function() {
  return om.start(function() {
    return console.log("connected with id " + om.id);
  });
};
start();
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is because of Timeout of your Internet Connection with Omegle, So it can be handled easily try to read the Callium Rogers documentation in npm/Omegle website and in Github too , use Try ctach over the function.

Comment: I have read the documentation and there is nothing written there about this error..
And I have also used the try catch, but in my case its not working at all.